# setDataFormat в SXSSF, Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, poi

Создал .xlsx файл, в который записываются данные большого объема с БД с помощью SXSSFWorkbook. Не получается форматирование текста в ячейках. Код такой:

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
SXSSFSheet excelSheet = workbook.createSheet(file_name);

SXSSFCreationHelper creationHelper = (SXSSFCreationHelper) workbook.getCreationHelper();
//XSSFCellStyle style_for_numbers = (XSSFCellStyle) workbook.createCellStyle();
CellStyle style_for_numbers = workbook.createCellStyle();
style_for_numbers.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
style_for_numbers.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
style_for_numbers.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
style_for_numbers.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);

//DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
//style_for_numbers.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("$#,##0.00"));
style_for_numbers.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("#,##0.00"));

......
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlQuery0);
......
while (rs.next()) {
SXSSFRow row1 = excelSheet.createRow(row_num);
for (int i = 1; i <= col_cnt; i++) {
SXSSFCell cell = row1.createCell(i-1);
cell.setCellValue(rs.getString(i) == null ? "" : rs.getString(i) );
cell.setCellStyle(style_for_numbers);
}
}
```

Границы ячеек отображаются, форматирование значений ячеек не происходит. Пробовал и с DataFormat и с SXSSFCreationHelper, менял SXSSF на XSSF, ничего не помогает. 
Здесь нашел нечто похожее: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54479, но у меня стиль ячеек создается за пределами цикла.... Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Олег,

Попробуйте использовать следующий вариант:

```
DataFormat dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
style_for_numbers.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00"));
```

Маленький псевдокод, который трансформировал из Вашего кода:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SXSSFTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\SXSSF.xlsx");
        SXSSFSheet excelSheet = wb.createSheet("Test Sheet");

        CellStyle style_for_numbers = wb.createCellStyle();
        style_for_numbers.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
        style_for_numbers.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
        style_for_numbers.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
        style_for_numbers.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);

        DataFormat dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style_for_numbers.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00"));

        SXSSFRow row1 = excelSheet.createRow(2);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            SXSSFCell cell = row1.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellValue(12312312);
            cell.setCellStyle(style_for_numbers);
        }

        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
}
```

Результат выполнения выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще один вариант, который по сути форматирует само значение, а не ставит стиль для всей ячейки (но это так... побаловаться):

```
cell.setCellValue(new CellNumberFormatter("#,##0.00").format(12312312));
```

Надеюсь поможет решить Вашу проблему.

Comment: Mikita Berazouski, большое спасибо за развернутый ответ! Я все делал как написали Вы, у меня не форматировалось, но с Вашей помощью я понял, что дело не в самом коде, а в данных, которые форматируются (у меня это нули и числа с десятичным разделителем в виде точки ). В результате помог парсинг: cellA1.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(rs.getString(i))

Comment: При этом когда было cellA1.setCellValue(rs.getString(i)), никакой ошибки не было, просто данные не форматировались. А с cell.setCellValue(new CellNumberFormatter("#,##0.00").format(Double.parseDouble("1234567.89"))); в ячейку записывается "1,234,567,,89.12". Понимаю, что дело в формате, но вроде бы погуглил - формат корректный.... Вообщем сейчас пытаюсь найти нужный формат. Еще раз большое спасибо за содержательный ответ!

Comment: А напишите 2-3 варианта чисел, которые Вы пытаетесь форматировать, чтобы более детально посмотреть.

Comment: @Oleg Похоже дело в том, что вы сетаете String. Поскольку с вариантом, который Вы указали, если делать число - `234567.89` тоже работает. Попробуйте: `cell.setCellValue(234567.89);`. Тут важно вставлять именно числовое значение, в нашем случае double, но ни в коем случае не строку. Если приходит строка, то `cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble("234567.89"));`

Comment: Числа например такие 2003;409.77;10002;23933.37;10088;0
Да, изначально я вставлял строку, поэтому значения не форматировались, сейчас пропарсил до Double - форматируется, спасибо! Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться с форматом (второй способ, предложенный Вами), пока не получается. Сейчас сброшу код.

Comment: Вроде тоже работает `cell.setCellValue(new CellNumberFormatter("#,##0.00").format(10088));` или `cell.setCellValue(new CellNumberFormatter("#,##0.00").format(23933.37));`. И опять-таки, только числа.

Answer (score 0):

Код переделанный из того, что Вы сбрасывали выше:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellNumberFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class datafrm {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\SXSSF.xlsx");
        SXSSFSheet excelSheet = wb.createSheet("Test Sheet");

        CellStyle style_for_numbers = wb.createCellStyle();
        style_for_numbers.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
        style_for_numbers.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
        style_for_numbers.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
        style_for_numbers.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);

        SXSSFRow row1 = excelSheet.createRow(2);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            SXSSFCell cell = row1.createCell(i);
            System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("1234567.89"));
            //cell.setCellValue(new CellNumberFormatter("#,##0.00").format(1234567.89));
            //cell.setCellValue(1234567.89);
            cell.setCellValue(new CellNumberFormatter("#,##0.00").format(Double.parseDouble("1234567.89")));
        }

        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        wb.close();
    }
}
```

Если я использую cell.setCellValue(new CellNumberFormatter("#,##0.00").format(Double.parseDouble("1234567.89")));
или cell.setCellValue(new CellNumberFormatter("#,##0.00").format(1234567.89));
то записывается "1,234,567,,89.12"
Почему так происходит форматирование, пока непонятно.

Comment: У меня этот код вставляет все отлично. Может дело в версии excel или poi? В моем случае это poi 3.16 и 2010 офис.

Comment: У меня тоже apache poi 3.16. Попробовал код выше в 13-ом и 7-ом офисе - результат один и тот же: в ячейку записывается "1,234,567,,89.12". Пробовал как выше cell.setCellValue(new CellNumberFormatter("#,##0.00").format(Double.parseDouble("1234567.89"))); , а также просто без парсинга: cell.setCellValue(new CellNumberFormatter("#,##0.00").format(1234567.89));

Comment: Ради интереса может залейте Ваш код куда-нибудь? чтобы локально можно было запустить.

Comment: Простите, немного Вас не понял, как и куда необходимо залить код? Код в точности как выше в этом ответе. Запускаю в эклипсе, но я думаю это не важно.

Comment: Я думал, что может все-таки есть какая-то кастомизация. А какая версия java? Пытаюсь найти отличие.

Comment: Попробуйте ради интереса запустить мой jar файл [excel_example.jar](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzIAzcoPpb5acnFpNU9lTi11ZEU). По двойному клику он создаст SXSSF.xlsx на диске `D:\`